# webrick and active_support (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, webrick

I've CentOS 5.8 x86_64 with RVM installed.
Under root I do:

```
1) rvm install ruby-1.9.2
2) rvm gemset create global
3) rvm gemset use global
4) gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
bundler (1.3.4)
daemon_controller (1.1.2)
fastthread (1.0.7)
minitest (1.6.0)
passenger (3.0.19)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (10.0.3, 0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)

5) ruby script/server

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': no such file to load -- active_support (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /var/www/html/lkdoctor/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'

6) gem which active_support

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support.rb
```

So I don't understand why Webrick doesn't see this gem!?

In fact I supressed that error with changing /config/boot.rb file with adding these lines:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'action_controller'
require 'active_record'
require 'action_mailer'
require 'active_resource'
```

However, I understand it is the wrong way.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have `Gemfile` in project (I guess `/var/www/html/lkdoctor`)?

Comment: No, this project are created by me, so no Gemfile.

Comment: can you add `gem env gempath` and  `echo $PATH`

Comment: Thanks for help. That is:

`[root@...]# gem env gempath
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global

[root@...]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`